# Elasticsearch boost a field when using query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to boost a field in a query of this form?

```
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "query_string": {
               "query": "the user's search query",
               "fields": ["name", "description"],
               "default_operator": "OR"
            }
         },
         "filter": {...}
      }
   }
```

Comment: do you want to boost only one field? like "name" only?
if you add the property boost below default_operator you can boot the query

Comment: I want to boost a single field only. The accepted answer below does exactly that. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, just add the boost syntax on the field (name^5), eg:

```
"query": {
   "filtered": {
      "query": {
         "query_string": {
            "query": "the user's search query",
            "fields": ["name^5", "description"],
            "default_operator": "OR"
         }
      },
      "filter": {...}
   }
}
```

Seems pretty clear in the docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boosting

Comment: If a query matches a field with less boost value i.e. 2 (when we have other fields with boost value of 5 ) and doesn't have a match in any of the other fields, simple_query_string query doesn't return any value, Will you be able to explain why?